# Are there any public APIs that will help determine the legality of a location to get Beer-Wine-Spirits delivered?

Tags: laws, united-states

Am after APIs that will in real-time help me understand by way of providing such APIs with the following inputs:

1. Store/Location Address/Geocoordinates of the location
2. Customer Address for receiving the delivery of Beer-Wine-Spirits (BWS)
3. Provide such an API with a slew of inputs like time of day and day of the week and the pointers discussed in 1 and 2 and the incumbent API should come back and tell me whether I can proceed onto delivering Beer-Wine-Spirits?
4. From Point 3, the API should also tell me whether I can ONLY deliver Beer or Wine or Spirits or All or what are the appropriate restrictions

Thanks for all the responses, I see that this post is still haunting me. Have to confirm that I managed to find a vendor - https://www.shipcompliant.com/ who happens to have all the information that I was after.

Comment: We need more input. What country are you talking about? If it's the USA, it's complicated... Plus I want a 10% cut of the profits of whatever app you are creating if I tell you where this information is.

Comment: It is hard to imagine this sort of thing would be freely available considering the legal implications. The provider would likely be liable for the consequences of any mistakes, and even if they were able to avoid liability then anyone who used it would need to verify its accuracy. So, in order to safely use such an API you would need to pretty much do all of the work to create it.

Comment: You can forget about that bounty. There is not enough information to go on, like what country is the OP even talking about...

Comment: Not an api (?) but good info: https://wineinstitute.compliancerules.org/
If it exists, it will likely be on the list at ProgrammableWeb.com.

Comment: You have added an answer into the post as an edit. It might be a good idea to post it as an answer and accept your own answer?

Comment: Probably more relevant now with Trumps new tariffs on whisky (etc) imports too